# Tree vertex coloring algorithm to maximize the number of blue vertices

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees, coloring, dynamic-programming

Assume that a tree $T$ is given and we want to assign a color to each vertex of it. **The color should be red or blue and no adjacent vertices can have color blue. (They can both be red but not blue)**

> Provide a linear time algorithm to assign colors (red or blue) to the vertices of
>   $T$ in a way that the number of blue vertices are maximized.

Any idea? I'm completely stuck... I don't know a way to start! it doesn't just want a simple coloring. It should be a coloring with maximizes the number of blue vertices. That's the entire point. How can we be sure that this condition is satisfied?

**Hint: Think of the dynamic programming approach.**

Comment: Do you have any restriction on coloring? May be adjacent vertices should have different colors?

Comment: @Smylic Yes... i forgot to write it... i'll make an edit

Comment: @Smylic the condition is a bit different... see the question again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part is about proper colorings. Any tree is connected bipartite graph. So when you color one vertex you can use either breadth-first search or depth-first search to color all other vertices, because when you push new vertex to a queue or stack you know the only appropriate color for it. Since you have only two possibilities to color the first vertex the time is linear, no DP is required.

---

This part is about maximum independent set. So after edit question become about maximum independent set (the set of blue vertices). For leave $v$ it is easy to see that there is maximum independent set $I_v$ that contains $v$. Really if some maximum independent set $I'$ doesn't contain $v$ than it should contain the only neighbor $u$ of $v$ because otherwise it is not maximal and therefore can not be maximum. Then $I_v = (I' \setminus \{\,u\,\}) \cup \{\,v\,\}$. Also if $\deg v = 0$ then $v$ obviously should be in each maximum independent set.

Therefore the algorithm is the following. Take arbitrary vertex of degree  0 or 1 leave color it into blue and remove this vertex from graph together with its neighbor if it exists. Continue while there are non-colored vertices. To make this approach efficient we can use queue (or stack) which contains all non-colored vertices of degree 0 or 1. Still no DP is required.

If DP is the only acceptable way then let's do the following. Do depth-first search (so the stack is required anyway). For each vertex $v$ compute the number of blue vertices in subtree of $v$ if $v$ is blue (number $f_b(v)$) and if $v$ is red (number $f_r(v)$). It is possible to compute it after computing for all children in the following way:
$$f_b(v) = 1 + \sum_{u \in N^+(v)} f_r(u),\\
f_r(v) = \sum_{u \in N^+(v)} \max\{\,f_r(u), f_b(u)\,\}.$$
This way also gives linear time.

Comment: Though you probably want $f_r(v) = \sum_u \max\{f_r(u), f_b(u)\}$, instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you!